# Display only one item from a database at a time and loop through others to display

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql

I'm trying to set up a page that displays one row of information from a news DB at a time.  It would display the first row for about 10 seconds, then swap to the next row of news for the same duration.  I found an answer from five years ago that seemed as though it would work, but each time I try to run it one of my variables becomes unreadable due to it being undefined.  Full code below:

```
<?php
  include('include/sqlsettings.php');
  $mysqli_conn = mysqli_connect($mysqli_host, $mysqli_user, $mysqli_pass, $mysqli_db);
  $query = 'SELECT * FROM news';
  $rs = mysqli_query($mysqli_conn, $query);
  $info = array();

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    array_push($info, array('title' => $row['id'],
                            'news' => $row['news'],
                            'location' => $row['location']));
    $infoData = json_encode(array('info' => $info));
    file_put_contents('info.json', $infoData);
  }
?>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul></ul>
  </body>
  <script src='/libs/js/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js'></script>
  <script>
    var i = 0,
        d = null,
        x = null,
        interval = 3000;

    $(document).ready(function(){
      fetch();
    });

    function fetch(){
      // get the data *once* when the page loads
      $.getJSON('info.json', function(data){
        // store the data in a global variable 'd'
        d = data.result;
        // create a recurring call to update()
        x = setInterval(function(){
          update()
        }, interval);
      });
    }

    function update(){
      // if there isn't an array element, reset to the first once
      if (!d[i]){
        clearInterval(x);
        i = 0;
        fetch();
        return;
      }
      // remove the previous items from the page
      $('ul').empty();
      // add the next item to the page
      $('ul').append(
        '<li>' + d[i]['title']
        + '</li><li>' + d[i]['news']
        + '</li><li>' + d[i]['location']
        + '</li>'
      );
      // increment for the next iteration
      i++;
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

The code errors out at `if(!d[i])` kicking back with
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined at update (<file>.php:33)` where d should be defined as the json data so I can loop through it.  I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're assigning `d` to to `data.result`. If `d` is `undefined`, it is because `data.result` is undefined. If it's possible for `data.result` to be `undefined`, consider doing the following check.

`if(d && !d[i])`

This will ensure `d` is defined before checking the index.

Comment: Thanks!  This helped me figure out that because the same document was creating and trying to reference the JSON file it didn't work.  They are now in separate files, no more errors, but still not where I want.

Definitely helped though :)